# a young woman who is pregnant

Tags: adjectives, postmodification

> a. In all this, he becomes involved in the life of a young woman, pregnant, whose husband, an environmental radical, wants an abortion.

FROM:

Andrew Sullivan, "[Obama’s Legacy Has Been Destroyed](https://newsstand.google.com/articles/CAIiEKgldeFVPlyQSufkeLsok1IqGQgEKhAIACoHCAowi_yDCzDblYADMKD-9QU)", New York Magazine May 18, 2018

Is (a) grammatical?

It is definitely understandable, but I don't like the way '*pregnant*' is placed. I think it should be *'who is pregnant'*.

If the '*a young woman*' was the subject of the sentence that kind of thing would work, but in this case, it is not the subject of the sentence.

Comment: In adopting a certain style, a critic may be less concerned with flowing, perfectly grammatical English than making a point..

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatical. It is a very abbreviated form of description, but I think it preserves the meaning. It also parallels the terse description of the husband.

I think he has done it that way because he is writing a short summary of the plot of the movie. (I also got the impression that he was writing in a rather staccato style to emphasise the bleakness of the movie -but that could just be me reading too much into it!)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the original phrase is totally correct.

[**pregnant**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pregnant) is an **adjective** and it goes along with a name, **woman**. It got the same functionality than **young** in that sentence.

The sentence could be rewritten

> In all this, he becomes involved in the life of a **young pregnant
>   woman**, whose husband, an environmental radical, wants an abortion

In the original one, the term **pregnant** is between commas establishing a pause to remark the relevant fact that she was pregnant.

Your approach may be correct but it doesn't sound natural to me. Let me rewrite again

> In all this, he becomes involved in the life of a woman, who is young
>   and is pregnant, whose husband, who is an environmental radical, wants
>   an abortion

Too bombastic.